# How to display the price in the checkbox tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I wanted to know how to display the price whenever I select a checkbox in tkinter, also if I select 2 checkbox it'll add the price. I've been trying it since yesterday and I still haven't figure out yet. The price that'll display will be on the same page as the checkbox.

Here's my overall code so far:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import * 

FOODS =  [('Vanilla', 80.00),
            ('Chocolate', 20.00),
            ('Strawberry', 40.00),
            ('Mango', 100.00),
            ('Pistachio', 35.00),
            ('Small', 200.00),
            ('Medium', 20.00),
            ('Large', 80.00),
            ('Marshmallow', 20.00),
            ('Chocolate chip', 40.00),
            ('Sprinkles', 100.00),
            ('Oreo', 35.00),
            ('Pearls', 200.00)]
class IceCream(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (Checkout, Exit):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(Checkout)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class Checkout(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Checkout", font="times 40 bold")
        label.pack(pady=50,padx=10)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Flavours", font="times 20 bold")
        label.place(x=15, y=120) 
        Checkbutton1 = IntVar()  
        Checkbutton2 = IntVar()  
        Checkbutton3 = IntVar()
        Checkbutton4 = IntVar()  
        Checkbutton5 = IntVar()
        Button1 = Checkbutton(self, text = "Vanilla", font="times 15",
                      variable = Checkbutton1,
                      onvalue = 1,
                      offvalue = 0,
                      height = 2,
                      width = 8)
                      
        Button1.place(x=0, y=150) 
        Button2 = Checkbutton(self, text = "Chocolate", font="times 15",
                      variable = Checkbutton2,
                      onvalue = 1,
                      offvalue = 0,
                      height = 2,
                      width = 10)
                      
        Button2.place(x=0, y=200) 
        Button3 = Checkbutton(self, text = "Strawberry", font="times 15",
                      variable = Checkbutton3,
                      onvalue = 1,
                      offvalue = 0,
                      height = 2,
                      width = 11)
                      
        Button3.place(x=0, y=250) 
        Button4 = Checkbutton(self, text = "Mango", font="times 15",
                      variable = Checkbutton4,
                      onvalue = 1,
                      offvalue = 0,
                      height = 2,
                      width = 7)
                      
        Button4.place(x=0, y=300) 
        Button5 = Checkbutton(self, text = "Pistachio", font="times 15",
                      variable = Checkbutton5,
                      onvalue = 1,
                      offvalue = 0,
                      height = 2,
                      width = 9)
        Button5.place(x=0, y=350) 
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Size", font="times 20 bold")
        label.place(anchor = 'c', x=280, y=135) 
        Checkbutton1 = IntVar()  
        Checkbutton2 = IntVar()  
        Checkbutton3 = IntVar()
        Checkbutton4 = IntVar()  
        Checkbutton5 = IntVar()
        Button1 = Checkbutton(self, text = "Small", font="times 15",
                      variable = Checkbutton1,
                      onvalue = 1,
                      offvalue = 0,
                      height = 2,
                      width = 10)
                      
        Button1.place(anchor = 'c',x=280, y=175) 
        Button2 = Checkbutton(self, text = "Medium", font="times 15",
                      variable = Checkbutton2,
                      onvalue = 1,
                      offvalue = 0,
                      height = 2,
                      width = 10)
                      
        Button2.place(anchor = 'c',x=280, y=225) 
        Button3 = Checkbutton(self, text = "Large", font="times 15",
                      variable = Checkbutton3,
                      onvalue = 1,
                      offvalue = 0,
                      height = 2,
                      width = 12)
                      
        Button3.place(anchor = 'c',x=280, y=275) 
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Toppings", font="times 20 bold")
        label.place(x=430, y=120) 
        Checkbutton1 = IntVar()  
        Checkbutton2 = IntVar()  
        Checkbutton3 = IntVar()
        Checkbutton4 = IntVar()  
        Checkbutton5 = IntVar()
        Button1 = Checkbutton(self, text = "Marshmallows", font="times 15",
                      variable = Checkbutton1,
                      onvalue = 1,
                      offvalue = 0,
                      height = 2,
                      width = 10)
                      
        Button1.place(x=420, y=153) 
        Button2 = Checkbutton(self, text = "Chocolate Chip", font="times 15",
                      variable = Checkbutton2,
                      onvalue = 1,
                      offvalue = 0,
                      height = 2,
                      width = 12)
                      
        Button2.place(x=400, y=203) 
        Button3 = Checkbutton(self, text = "Sprinkles", font="times 15",
                      variable = Checkbutton3,
                      onvalue = 1,
                      offvalue = 0,
                      height = 2,
                      width = 12)
                      
        Button3.place(x=420, y=250)
        Button4 = Checkbutton(self, text = "Oreos", font="times 15",
                      variable = Checkbutton4,
                      onvalue = 1,
                      offvalue = 0,
                      height = 2,
                      width = 10)
                      
        Button4.place(x=420, y=303)
        Button5 = Checkbutton(self, text = "Pearls", font="times 15",
                      variable = Checkbutton5,
                      onvalue = 1,
                      offvalue = 0,
                      height = 2,
                      width = 10)
        Button5.place(x=420, y=350)
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Start Again", font="times 15",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Start))
        button1.place(x=20, y=450)

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Exit", font="times 15",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Exit))
        button2.place(x=200, y=450)
        
class Exit(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Thank you, " + '\n' + "Have a Good Day!!!", font="times 50 bold")
        label.pack(anchor="c", ipady=180,ipadx=0)
        
        
app = IceCream()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here. Also, it is better to use a dictionary here

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import * 

FOODS =  {'Vanilla':80.00,
            'Chocolate': 20.00,
            'Strawberry': 40.00,
            'Mango':100.00,
            'Pistachio':35.00
            }
SIZE={'Small':200.00,
            'Medium': 20.00,
            'Large':80.00,
            }
TOPPPINGS={'Marshmallow':20.00,
            'Chocolate chip': 40.00,
            'Sprinkles':100.00,
            'Oreo':35.00,
            'Pearls':200.00}
class IceCream(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (Checkout, Exit):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(Checkout)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class Checkout(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Checkout", font="times 40 bold")
        label.pack(pady=50,padx=10)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Flavours", font="times 20 bold")
        label.place(x=15, y=120) 
        self.sum_total=0
        self.total_lbl=Label(self,font=("arial",17,'bold'),text=f'Total: {self.sum_total}')
        self.total_lbl.place(x=300,y=450)
        size=150
        for j,i in FOODS.items():
            new_var=i
            i=IntVar()
            Checkbutton(self,text=j,variable=i,font="times 15",offvalue=0,onvalue=1,command=lambda i=i,j=new_var: self.receive(i,j)).place(x=10,y=size)
            size+=50
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Size", font="times 20 bold")
        label.place(anchor = 'c', x=280, y=135) 
        size2=175
        for l,k in SIZE.items():
            new_var2=k
            k=IntVar()
            Checkbutton(self,text=l,variable=k,font="times 15",offvalue=0,onvalue=1,command=lambda k=k,l=new_var2: self.receive(k,l)).place(x=230,y=size2)
            size2+=50
                      
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Toppings", font="times 20 bold")
        label.place(x=430, y=120) 
        size3=153
        for n,m in TOPPPINGS.items():
            new_var3=m
            m=IntVar()
            Checkbutton(self,text=n,variable=m,font="times 15",offvalue=0,onvalue=1,command=lambda m=m,n=new_var3: self.receive(m,n)).place(x=400,y=size3)
            size3+=50
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Start Again", font="times 15",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(IceCream))
        button1.place(x=20, y=450)

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Exit", font="times 15",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Exit))
        button2.place(x=200, y=450)
        
    def receive(self,var,val):
        if var.get()==0:
            self.sum_total-=val
        else:
            self.sum_total+=val
        self.total_lbl.config(text=f'Total: {int(self.sum_total)}')
class Exit(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Thank you, " + '\n' + "Have a Good Day!!!", font="times 50 bold")
        label.pack(anchor="c", ipady=180,ipadx=0)
        
        
app = IceCream()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Should `Radiobutton` be used on size selection?

Comment: @acw1668, I just compressed OP's code. Also, one can ask for 2 or more sizes?

Comment: Question, How can I move/ position the "Total: " in that code? @Sujay

Comment: @MacnChz, change the value of x,y in ```.place```

Comment: is it this one? " self.receive(m,n)).place(x=400,y=size3)" @Sujay

Comment: No @MacnChz, it is ```self.total_lbl.place(x=300,y=450)```

Comment: Sorry I didn't saw that, Thank you so much for your help :) Sorry @Sujay I can't upvote it because I need 15 reputation to cast a vote, but I already accept ur answer :)

Comment: No problem @MacnChz :)